# Why is encrypted volume asking for password on first run only?

Tags: automator, password, encryption, dmg

MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina. I have a “QuitAllApps.app” automation that quits all open apps, including an encrypted .DMG volume that is opened with different automation.

After working great for a few years, the “QuitAllApps.app” still shuts open apps down but if I reopen the encrypted volume, without restarting or shutting down the MacBook Pro, it opens without requiring the password.

Get info on the volume and it’s two containers has all three listed as not encrypted, despite that I’m asked for the password on the first one after I restart the shut down.

[image: QuitAllApps.app automation]

Comment: Is the password in the keychain?

Comment: No. I’m ok manually putting it in. A shortcut I use on my iPad Pro wakes/logs into the Mac. Then applescript launches the Run Plex Launch.app seen here. iPad then opens my Remote+ App so I can enter code to mount the encrypted volume, then I return to SC so it can set lights, etc. The “Quit All Apps” Mac  automation unmounts volume after a set amount of time, re-setting the need for a password when it was again mounted. This is what I can’t fix. I have to shut the Mac down for reset to happen rather then just quitting the launch automation. Perhaps this started when I addded in the iPad SC?